# click animates title bar up, slidesdown a panel open, how do I click again to animate down raised bar and close panel?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a container with a title bar and a panel below it that is hidden until the title bar is clicked, which then slidesDown the panel and raises the title bar up several pixels. This works fine. What I need to be able to do after it is open, is to click the title bar and have it drop back down to its starting position, while still closing the panel and hiding again. When I click the title bar after open, the panel closes and disappears, but the title bar remains in the raised position (because I have nothing to lower it back down). I've tried a few different options.

**html**

```
<div id="specialsEventsContainer" style="float:left">
    <div id="specialsEventsTitle" style="top: 90px">
        <p>Specials & Events</p></div>
    <div class="promobox">
      <div id="revealDown" style="height: 0; display:block;">

        <div id="specialscalendarPortals">
            <div class="halfsizeBoxes" style="float:left">
                <a href=""><p>text text text</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="halfsizeBoxes">
                <a href=""><p>Tulalip Resort-Casino Calendar Portal</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="fullsizeBoxes">
        <a href=""><img src="~/Content/Images/promoimage.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="fullsizeBoxes">
        <a href=""><img src="~/Content/Images/promoimage.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="fullsizeBoxes" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
        <a href=""><img src="~/Content/Images/promoimage.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**jquery**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

                var $spTitle = $('#specialsEventsTitle');
                var $promobox = $('#revealDown');

                $($spTitle).click(function () {
                $spTitle.animate({ top: '8px' });

                if ($promobox.height() > 0) {
                    $promobox.animate({ height: 0 });
                } else {
                    $promobox.animate('slow').animate({ height: '100%' });
                 }
            });
        });
     </script>
```

Comment: Care to provide your CSS also? Post a jsfiddle would be most helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than this:

```
$spTitle.animate({ top: '8px' });
```

use this:

```
if (parseInt($spTitle).css('top') > 0 )
    $spTitle.animate({ top: '0px' });
else
     $spTitle.animate({ top: '8px' });
```

Comment: I've put a second click function in that works beautifully, until you do a second click on it. I know it can't be embedded in the first animate click.$($spTitle).click(function () {
                $spTitle.animate({ top: '90px' });
            });

Comment: Couldn't use your answer as part of mine without at least up voting it. +1

Comment: I have the fix. I can't post the answer until later because I'm new on here and stackoverflow won't allow me to. The software engineer here reworked it and made it a little more involved. I think what your guys were showing would have worked too if I understood a little bit more. Thanks.

Comment: Should've been pretty straight forward for a software engineer in the first place, no?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the perfect case for `.slideToggle`.

You can see the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

            var $spTitle = $('#specialsEventsTitle');
            var $promobox = $('#revealDown');

            $($spTitle).click(function () {
            $promobox.slideToggle('slow', function() {
                if (parseInt($spTitle).css('top') > 0 )
                    $spTitle.animate({ top: '0px' });
                else
                    $spTitle.animate({ top: '8px' });
            });

        });
    });
 </script>
```

I also included Rob R's answer as it looks correct and I was in the middle of working around that solution aswell. Code is untested though.

Comment: But I need to include the promobox (panel) as well to react to the clicking action. When the title bar is clicked, then it raises while the promobox slidesdown. Then when the title bar (or anywhere) is clicked, it drops back to its original place and the promobox (panel) closes. I am very green, so please excuse me if I am getting some of this incorrect. The slideToggle just makes the title bar go up and down and never drops the promobox. I see that Rob R's might be close, but how do I have two if/else statements in one function?

Comment: My bad, edited already. So on clicking `$spTitle` > `$promobox` opens > `$spTitle` moves.

Comment: Didn't work either. Must be something I'm doing or have in the way. Thanks though. I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm guessing your styles probably have something to do with it. Also, if it doesn't need to visually animate you can toggle the classes much easier.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of what you have then?

Comment: Okay, I created a fiddle account. But my code isn't working on fiddle. This is a MVC 4 project and I've bundled the jquery, but the jquery for the promo container is on the html page - just until I got it figured out. http://jsfiddle.net/DhalCarroll/NwFvZ/

Comment: Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/NwFvZ/11/ jquery will not return the correct 'top' position value using their .css() method, unless you have { position: absolute } specified in your CSS. otherwise your top position returns 'auto' since it is in the normal document flow. make sense?

Comment: Nice, right on the money, maybe if you edit it into my answer we can share cred?? Not sure if that'll work though.