# Collapse multiple objects with same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make navigation that supports expand toggle.

I got 2 child navigation items I want to show but it only displays first one, it should display both items.
How I can make this to show each item with same ID?

```
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#nav1" class="nav-toggle">Example <span class="nav-plus"></span></a>
      <li id="nav1" style="display:none;"><div class="orange-bar"></div><a href="page1.php">Navigation 1</a></li>
      <li id="nav1" style="display:none;"><div class="orange-bar"></div><a href="page2.php">Navigation 2</a></li>
    </ul>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.nav-toggle').click(function(){
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');                   
        var toggle_switch = $(this);

        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function(){
          if($(this).css('display')=='none'){
            toggle_switch.html('Example <span class="nav-plus"></span>');
          }else{
            toggle_switch.html('Example <span class="nav-minus"></span>');
          }
        });
        return false;
      });

    }); 
    </script>
```

This is just example of navigation, there will be multiple expand navigation items.

Comment: `ID`s are unique and can only be specified for one element on a page. Use `Classes`.

Comment: Ids are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Check out this question, very similar task, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071903/click-animates-title-bar-up-slidesdown-a-panel-open-how-do-i-click-again-to-an/17072655#comment24698567_17072655 ideally you want to use `.slideToggle` but first you need to get a grasp on `HTML` and `CSS` basics.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you are using ids in a non-unique way. Ids are meant to be unique. Use a class instead.

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href=".nav1" class="nav-toggle">Example <span class="nav-plus"></span></a></li>
    <li class="nav1" style="display:none;"><div class="orange-bar"></div><a href="page1.php">Navigation 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav1" style="display:none;"><div class="orange-bar"></div><a href="page2.php">Navigation 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Notice I changed the href to ".nav1" and I changed the ids on the subsequent li tags to classes. This will cause both items to show. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/judeosborn/KRf7T/) for proof.

Also, the first li was missing a closing tag, so I fixed that as well.

This will fix your problem, but it feels a bit convoluted to me. It's a bit unusual to use an href attribute to refer to the ids or classes of other elements. You may want to consider a different approach, such as:

```
  $('.nav-toggle').click(function(){
    var collapse_content_selector = $(this).closest('ul').find('.nav1');                   
    var toggle_switch = $(this);

    $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function(){
      if($(this).css('display')=='none'){
        toggle_switch.html('Example <span class="nav-plus"></span>');
      }else{
        toggle_switch.html('Example <span class="nav-minus"></span>');
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
```

Notice that instead of using the href to find the subsequent li tags I'm finding the parent ul and then looking for any li tags that have the class "nav1". There are lots of ways to accomplish this, but you'll probably find this is a cleaner approach. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/judeosborn/KRf7T/3/) for a live example.